# Count occurrences of a string in a table grouped by date and row header in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a over a year's worth of daily activity data for a large group of people (2 rows per person for morning and afternoon) in a table that I need to report on by name and month for any given activity. A sample of the data is:

| NAME | 29-May | 30-May | 31-May | 1-Jun | 2-Jun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | Support | Leave | Support | Support | Support |
| Bill | Support | Leave | Support | Support | Support |
| Ted | Ops | Ops | Ops | Ops | Leave |
| Ted | Ops | Ops | Ops | Leave | Leave |
| Bob | Training | Training | Training | Support | Support |
| Bob | Support | Support | Support | Support | Support |
| Jay | Ops | Ops | Ops | Ops | Ops |
| Jay | Support | Support | Support | Support | Support |

I have a cell (F14 in the image below) that uses a data validated list to allow the user to pick a specific activity to report on (e.g. Support).

The format I need for the data is a count of occurrences of the selected activity type for each person, broken down by month, e.g.

| NAME | May-21 | Jun-21 | Jul-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | 2 | 0 |  |
| Ted | 0 | 3 |  |
| Bob | 0 | 0 |  |
| Jay | 0 | 0 |  |

I'm sure I've done this in the past with a formula that I can then stretch across all rows in the results/report area and then stretch down through all rows. A one formula fits all approach, using strategically placed $s.

The formula I'm using in the top left cell of the report section is as follows, but what I'm getting are #VALUE! errors instead of numbers/counts.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$9,$A15,$A$1:$F$1,">="&B$14,$A$1:$F$1,"<"&C$14,$A$2:$F$9,$F$14)
```

A COUNTIFS of each of the criteria separately gives the correct count, e.g. COUNTIFS($A$2:$F$9,$F$14) results in 5 when F14 is "Leave".

What should the formula be to get the result I'm after? Could the result I'm after be achieved another way, and if so, how?

[image: Excel screenshot of data table and the desired output format]

Comment: The ranges passed to `COUNTIFS` must be of an equal dimension. Try forming the product of your conditional statements (within parentheses) and passing the final result to a suitable aggregating function, e.g. `SUMPRODUCT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUMPRODUCT` will work in this case:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$F$9=$F$14)*(TEXT(B$14,"MM.yyyy")=TEXT($B$1:$F$1,"MM.yyyy"))*($A15=$A$2:$A$9))
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. Now to play around with it and understand how it does it's magic (also part of the fun).